# Azure functions cannot access mscorelib.dll access denied

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have been working with Azure functions and have run into this error:

> Error: Could not load file or assembly '9008 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

when I open any function that I have written or a new function and the console error:

> error CS0009: Metadata file 'D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' could not be opened -- Access to the path is denied.

when I attempt to run. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew,

Restarting the site should mitigate this issue. But we do want to follow up on this to provide a better root cause. Would you mind sharing your function app name either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) so we can further investigate?

Comment: Thank you. That worked. If do find the root cause, I would like to know. This is our function app: http://nyxfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information! I took a closer look and the issue and have a theory that this might have been caused by an incorrect reference in your project.json file (looks like there was a typo, which was corrected but looks like things were in a bad state) that generated an invalid lock file. I'll try to repro this, but just wanted to share more information.