# Why do I get an exception in Azure functions where mscorlib says access denied?

Tags: .net, azure, f#, azure-functions

Starting my Azure Functions gets the following exception:

```
2017-12-19T23:32:29.318 F# HTTP trigger function processed a request.

2017-12-19T23:32:29.504 Exception while executing function: Functions.XYZ. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. mscorlib: Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11388' is denied.

2017-12-19T23:32:29.551 Function completed (Failure, Id=233a8f97-34c9-4eb6-a333-7e3d726c7bac, Duration=698ms)
```

I restarted the function multiple times as I read in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912771/azure-functions-cannot-access-mscorelib-dll-access-denied).

My function is in F# and uses FSharp.Data so i added it to the project.json file

```
 {
  "frameworks": {
  "net46":{
  "dependencies": {
    "FSharp.Interop.Dynamic": "3.0.0",
    "FSharp.Data": "2.4.3"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

In my function I added the `open FSharp.Data` statement.
I think #r isn't necessary, is it?

Any idea what I can do? Thx

---

Update

If the trigger fires the following exception is thrown

```
F# HTTP trigger function processed a request.

Exception while executing function: Functions.LMWarnungVerbessern

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.LMWarnungVerbessern ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11388' is denied.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,String maybeFullPath)

at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,FileMode mode,FileAccess access,Int32 rights,Boolean useRights,FileShare share,Int32 bufferSize,FileOptions options,SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,String msgPath,Boolean bFromProxy,Boolean useLongPath,Boolean checkHost)

at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,FileMode mode,FileAccess access,FileShare share)

at FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncRead@237-5.Invoke(Unit unitVar) at C:\Git\FSharp.Data\src\CommonRuntime\IO.fs : 237

at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.callA@851.Invoke(AsyncParams`1 args)

at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.commit[a](Result`1 res)

at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps.RunSynchronously[a](CancellationToken token,FSharpAsync`1 computation,FSharpOption`1 timeout)

at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T](FSharpAsync`1 computation,FSharpOption`1 timeout,FSharpOption`1 cancellationToken) 

End of inner exception

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,Object[] arguments,Signature sig,Boolean constructor)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,Object[] parameters,Object[] arguments)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,BindingFlags invokeAttr,Binder binder,Object[] parameters,CultureInfo culture)

at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,Function…
```

---

Update 2

It happens as soon as I use:

```
let! doc = HtmlDocument.AsyncLoad(url) //same with HtmlDocument.Load
```

As a workaround I now use the WebClient to Download it and then parse the text:

```
let wc = new WebClient()
let lines = wc.DownloadString url
let doc = HtmlDocument.Parse lines
```

Comment: What is the authentication mode which you are using for your function. Like anonymous or function mode.

Comment: It's set to function mode but same with anonymous